# Implementing a web service orchestration with BPEL in java and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, bpel, orchestration, apache-ode

I've been reading a lot of different tutorials for creating web services, but none of these could help me create a web service with a BPEL orchestration of web services.

How can I implement a java program that uses a BPEL orchestration to keep track of the web services being used and how can I communicate with these in the best way?

I am new to SOA, BPEL and so on so this question might seem dumb, but is the BPEL (document/code) supposed to be located at the server (web service) or at the client side?

If anyone could help me out or maybe show me some good tutorials on this topic, I would really appreciate it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bpel code is located at server side.

You could create a java program which access your bpel process, after exposing it like a web service.

Example:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/matjaz-bpel1-090575.html

But there are better options for orchestration, like Oracle Service Bus.